# ng-options disabled in array

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, ng-controller

I have a view that manages school's tests in a period (trimester or semester). Each semester can have many tests of type normal but only one of type examen.

I have made a script in jsFiddle that shows the behavior I am looking for https://jsfiddle.net/dfLf9zkm/.

The difference is that in the ng-repeat I have a ng-controller over each test so every time I called the ng-method it only affects the row I am on and not the rest. Something like

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Controller">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Ponderation</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="test in tests track by test.id" ng-controller="TestRow">
            <td><select ng-model="test.type" ng-options="type.id as type.type disable when type.id == 2 && hasExam && idExam!=test.id for type in types" ng-change="checkTests()"></select>
            </td>
            <td>{{test.ponderation}}%</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

If I change the value of $scope.hasExam with a method inside TestRow controller it only affect that row and not the rest. How can I do it?

Comment: There's absolutely no need for another controller `TestRow`. The main controller can handle the ng-change by doing `ng-change="checkTests(test)"`. If this isn't helpful, could you please clarify what's the purpose of `hasExam`?

Comment: I am not able to understand when you say `How can I do it?` ? Please explain in better way on what you are expecting ? Also, @Protozoid mentioned a valid point, why to create `controller` for each row by putting it with `ng-repeat`

Comment: The code was already made in that way. HasExam checks if there is already an exam in that period. All the tests are obtained with a factory. In the example I gave hard coded tests but obviously it does not work in that way in the real case.
The other controller carries out some methods to update and manages a datepicker plugin that it was created to handle a date field

Answer (score -1):

I finally decided to leave everything in one controller and that fixed everything up